# Should the '.jshintrc' and 'karma.conf.js', part of the Jasmine 'test' folder be version controlled

Tags: javascript, angularjs, git, karma-jasmine

I am using a set of files generated by the yeomen's angular generator. When it comes to version controlling via Git, these two files ('.jshintrc' and 'karma.conf.js') aren't included and I was wondering if they should be since am working as part of a team?

Also, am intrigued how those two files are being ignore by Git in the first place since my .gitignore files doesn't mention them:

```
 /node_modules
/dist
/.tmp
/.sass-cache
/bower_components
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually, the files aren't excluded at all. It's just that I haven't made any changes to them, hence why they aren't showing as part of the staged or modified files.

And I am now convinced those two files must version controlled.